# Seg fault before main even runs?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, program-entry-point

I'm receiving a segmentation fault before my main even runs any significant code capable of causing a seg fault. Namely, `printf("before main functionality starts\n");` is not running.

What could be causing this problem?

```html
 int main() {
  printf("before main functionality starts\n"); 
  person* people = create();
  
  //Make new file and write into it
  printf("\nWriting into file\n");
  char file_name[] = "people_list";
  int file_number = open(file_name, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0644); //only owner can read/write, rest can only read

  int error_check;
  error_check = write(file_number, people, sizeof(&people) ); //reads array into file
 
  if(error_check < 0) {
    printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }
  close(file_number);

  //Read from new file
  printf("\nReading from file...\n");
  person* new_people[10];
  file_number = open(file_name, O_RDONLY); //reopens file, now with data
  error_check = read(file_number, new_people, sizeof(people));
  if(error_check < 0) {
    printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }
  close(file_number);
```

Comment: Putting code in the question rather than a screenshot is preferred

Comment: My apologies. Developing a migraine, and my terminal refuses to cooperate with my copy-pasting ventures.

Comment: You're segfaulting because you're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer (`first`). You aren't seeing "`woops`" because you aren't flushing the output stream, not because `printf` isn't being called.

Comment: Can you explain what flushing the output stream means? I'm still relatively new to C.

Comment: @CodeSammich if the C runtime automatically flushed the standard output stream every time it was written to, it would be an extremely costly thing to `printf`. Instead it flushes the stream buffer every time a newline character is encountered. You can cause a flush by printing a newline character at the end of your string `"woops\n"`, flushing it explicitly before the next newline `fflush(stdout)` or use unbuffered output `fprintf(stderr, "woops")`.

Comment: @CodeSammich oh, and "flushing the output stream" simply means actually displaying what's contained in the output buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see output immediately then you need to flush the handle (using `fflush(stdio)`).  Your program is very likely crashing after the `printf` call that it issues immediately.

IO is also flushed on end of line, so if you have your debug statement end in `'\n'` then it will be displayed and you will find where your segmentation fault is happening.

Comment: Flush with fflush(stdio);

Comment: picked this as answer: more relevant to question in header.

Comment: Use `FILE* stdio = stdout;` or `FILE* stdio = stderr;` before `fflush(stdio);`

Answer (score 2):

In the image it is visible that you have  *not allocated* memory to struct .

Allocate memory to struct pointer `first` and `new` and then use them to access structure members.

```
person *first=malloc(sizeof *first);             //remember to free allocated memory
```

Comment: Don't we not need to allocate memory if the pointer resides inside the same method (main)?

Edit: it works, but I'm still unclear on the reason for malloc

Comment: @CodeSammich the pointer doesn't need allocating. But it needs to point to something, and that's often a dynamically allocated object. If you didn't want to use dynamic allocation you'd just write `person first;` without using a pointer for the root node of your tree at all.

Comment: @CodeSammich You will need to initialize the pointer , and also C don't have methods :-)

Comment: @ameyCU Woops, I meant functions*

I understand. Thank you! (I really need some sleep...)

Comment: @CodeSammich don't over-use `malloc` for no reason. If your `struct person`s implementation is always going to be visible, prefer automatic duration (plain variables over `malloc`ed ones).